# Copy (Clipboard Module) missing for ag-grid-vue

Tags: node-modules, clipboard, ag-grid, missing-features, ag-grid-vue

I noticed that ag-grid-vue and @ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules does not include the Clipboard module. Copy, copy with headers, and paste are all missing in the context menu.

```
/* Package.json */
 "dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "^22.1.2",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/clipboard": "^22.1.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^22.1.1",
    "ag-grid-vue": "^22.1.1"
```

[context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lALrz.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ng build --prod failed after ag-grid v 22.1.1 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60107869/ng-build-prod-failed-after-ag-grid-v-22-1-1-upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

you can try installing 
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/clipboard": "^22.1.1" in the package.json.

then add this in the app.component.ts file

import {ModuleRegistry} from 'ag-grid-community';
import {ClipboardModule} from '@ag-grid-enterprise/clipboard';

ModuleRegistry.register(ClipboardModule as any);

this worked for me. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

You are currently mixing the two approaches of including AG Grid in your project.

You only need the following in your package.json file as these packages contain all the code you need following the AG Grid 'package' approach. The package `ag-grid-enterprise` contains the Clipboard functionality without the need to register modules.

```json
/* Package.json */
 "dependencies": {
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^22.1.2",
    "ag-grid-community": "^22.1.1",
    "ag-grid-vue": "^22.1.1"
```

From the [docs](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/modules/#mixing-packages-and-modules)

> It is important that you do not mix packages and modules in the same
> application as this will result in AG Grid being included twice and
> doubling your bundle size! All modules are scoped by either
> @ag-grid-community/* or @ag-grid-enterprise/* and should not be mixed
> with the standalone packages of ag-grid-community and
> ag-grid-enterprise.

| Modules | Packages |
| --- | --- |
| @ag-grid-community/xxxxx | ag-grid-community |
| @ag-grid-enterprise/xxxxx | ag-grid-enterprise |

I have written about this more in this [blog post](https://blog.ag-grid.com/minimising-bundle-size/).